# Printing Flex 4 application in Firefox using browser print

Tags: flash, apache-flex, firefox, printing

There is a wide known issue with printing of Flash content in Firefox and Chrome browsers.So,one [solution](http://www.anychart.com/blog/2011/02/24/printing-flash-content-in-firefox/) was created by "AnyCharts".But it seems not to work.I also tried to implement [the latest version of the component](http://code.google.com/p/flash-print-fix/) that is now hosted and Google Code.I did exactly as the manual prescribes but it still doesn't work.AnyChart guys say on their blog page that something should be done with CSS as well ,but as you can see from the manual at [Flash-Print-Fix](http://code.google.com/p/flash-print-fix/) home page ,there is no mention about CSS setup.

My code works like this:

In HTML I connect the JavaScript class supplied with Flash_Print-Fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="lib/FlashPrintFix.js"></script>
```

In Flex App I put this line inside FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE handler for the chart series:

```
private function  onLineComplete(e:Event):void{

     FlashPrintFix.initializeApp();
    }
```

It doesn't work.Print Preview is still empty.

Anybody has a detailed setup explanation of how to solve this issue? 
Thanks.

Update:
Well after some deeper research I found the problem.The thing is that inside the Flex FlashPrintFix utility the following line is the critical one:

```
 ExternalInterface.call("FlashPrintFix.setImg", ExternalInterface.objectID,    _base64encoder.toString());
```

The ExternalInterface.objectID parameter must be set,otherwise the JS side of the utility will not find the Flash Object.Somehow ,still don't understand why,if I embed the Flash using one of available JQuery plugins ExternalInterface.objectID is empty.So the workaround is to hard type the Flash Object id  in the JS class of the Utility :
Inside FlashPrintFix.js:

```
FlashPrintFix.setImg = function(objId, imgData) {
   var obj = document.getElementById(yourFlashObjectID");
 ...
 .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post some more code to help.

The Code sample in that link works fine for me. the preview came as like the application.
It created Image and placed in html below the flash content as like

[image: Print Flash]

Check Where You left.

1) use debugger to check whether it get initialized or not.

2) If u get the image below as like then it will show the preview.